# Converting 2D array of numbers into chars

Tags: c, arrays, char, maze

I am making a maze using Depth-First search algorithm as a school project. The maze is working pretty much as I want but I have a little problem. I have to use `#` as a wall and `.` as a path when printing the maze but I used `0` as a wall and `1` as a path at first thinking that it is gonna be easy to change it later but I was wrong. How can I change `0` and `1` into `#` and `.`?

### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void nahodne_suradnice(int *r, int *s, int n)
{
srand(time(NULL));
*r = ((rand() % n) - 1) + 2;
if (*r == 1 || *r == n)
{
    *s = (rand() % n) + 2;
}
else
{
    if (rand() % 2 == 1)
        *s = 1;
    else
        *s = n;
}
}
int main()
{
int i, j, n, r, s,smer,posledny_smer[1500];
int maze[500][500];
scanf_s("%d", &n);
if (n < 10 || n > 100)
{
    return 0;
}
//vynulovanie pola/bludiska
for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < n + 1; j++)
    {
        maze[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
//nahodny vyber zaciatku bludiska
nahodne_suradnice(&r, &s, n);

//generovanie bludiska
j = 0;
maze[r][s] = 2;
for (i = 0 ;; i++)
{
    //backtracking
    if ((maze[r - 1][s] == 1 || maze[r - 2][s] == 1 || r - 2 <=1 || s==n || s==1) && (maze[r][s + 1] == 1 || maze[r][s + 2] == 1 || s + 2 >= n || r == n || r==1) && (maze[r + 1][s] == 1 || maze[r + 2][s] == 1 || r + 2 >= n || s == n || s==1) && (maze[r][s - 1] == 1 || maze[r][s - 2] == 1 || s - 2 <=1 || r == n || r==1))
    {
        if (posledny_smer[j-1] == 1)
            if (maze[r + 1][s] == 1 && maze[r + 2][s] == 1)
            {
                r += 2;
                j--;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
                continue;
            }
        if (posledny_smer[j-1] == 2)
            if (maze[r][s - 1] == 1 && maze[r][s - 2] == 1)
            {
                s -= 2;
                j--;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
                continue;
            }
        if (posledny_smer[j-1] == 3)
            if (maze[r - 1][s] == 1 && maze[r - 2][s] == 1)
            {
                r -= 2;
                j--;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
                continue;
            }
        if (posledny_smer[j-1] == 4)
            if (maze[r][s + 1] == 1 && maze[r][s + 2] == 1)
            {
                s += 2;
                j--;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
                continue;
            }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            if (r == n)
            {
                nahodne_suradnice(&r, &s,n);
                maze[1][s] = 3;
                maze[2][s] = 3;
            }
            if (r == 1)
            {
                nahodne_suradnice(&r, &s, n);
                maze[n][s] = 3;
                maze[n - 1][s] = 3;
            }
            if (s == n-2)
            {
                nahodne_suradnice(&r, &s, n);
                maze[r][1] = 3;
                maze[r][2] = 3;
            }
            if (s == 3)
            {
                nahodne_suradnice(&r, &s, n);
                maze[r][n] = 3;
                maze[r][n-1] = 3;
            }

                break;
        }
    }
    //buranie stien
    smer = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    if (smer == 1)
    {
        if (r - 2 >1 && s<n && s>1)
        {
            if (maze[r - 1][s] == 1 || maze[r - 2][s] == 1)
                continue;
            maze[r - 1][s] = 1;
            maze[r - 2][s] = 1;
            r -= 2;
            posledny_smer[j] = smer;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (smer == 2)
    {
        if (s + 2 < n && r < n && r>1)
        {
            if (maze[r][s+1] == 1 || maze[r][s+2] == 1)
                continue;
            maze[r][s + 1] = 1;
            maze[r][s + 2] = 1;
            s += 2;
            posledny_smer[j] = smer;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (smer == 3)
    {
        if (r + 2 < n && s < n && s>1)
        {
            if (maze[r + 1][s] == 1 || maze[r + 2][s] == 1)
                continue;
            maze[r + 1][s] = 1;
            maze[r + 2][s] = 1;
            r += 2;
            posledny_smer[j] = smer;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (smer == 4)
    {
        if (s - 2 >1 && r < n && r>1)
        {
            if (maze[r][s-1] == 1 || maze[r][s-2] == 1)
                continue;
            maze[r][s - 1] = 1;
            maze[r][s - 2] = 1;
            s -= 2;
            posledny_smer[j] = smer;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
    }
}


//vypis bludiska
for (i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < n + 1; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", maze[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

`

Thanks.

Comment: If you wrote the code (as you claim) there should be no problem for you to replace the characters or, at least, identify the exact problem with doing so. However, the vague description makes me think someone else wrote the code for you and you have no idea what it does. I do not think we should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition of maze to:

```
char maze[500][500]
```

and change all references to use char instead of int. Then return '#' and '.' instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: My answer may be a little over-simplified. Upon closer inspection of your code, I see that at one point, you are assigning the value 3 to the maze. I'm not sure why that is, but you may need to review what is going on there. It's hard for me to read the code because a lot of it appears to be in a foreign language.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from 0 and 1 to # and . (or any other representation) when printing.  For instance you can change:

```
printf("%d", maze[i][j]);
```

to

```
switch(maze[i][j]) {
  case 0:
    printf("#");
    break;
  case 1:
    printf(".");
    break;
  default:
    printf("X"); /* in case you have some value other than 0 or 1 in the maze */
 }
```

If you do it like this, you can change which letters you want to display the maze as without changing other parts of your code.